# What does "apostrophe s" stand for in "What's it all mean"?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions, auxiliary-verbs

I heard someone on a TV show say:

> What's it all mean?

As far as I know, *'s* could be the short form of *has* and *is*. But in this case, it seems more like to be the short form of *does*. Am I correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the chart of [English contractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29#English) on Wikipedia points out, *'s* can be used in place of *does* (as well as *is, has, was* and *as*).

It can also be used to represent the entirely unrelated *us*, as in *let's*.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you give me an example in which `as` has been contracted?

Comment: @Meysam got one: *We left early, so's not to be late.*

Comment: @Meysam: The non-standard 'That's as maybe' (meaning 'perhaps') can be contracted to 'that's's maybe' - although it would be rarely written other than as dialogue.

Comment: @BarrieEngland very hard to say that's's :D

Comment: @BarrieEngland Now that I think, it's not that hard if the first `'s` is pronounced 's' and the second is pronounced 'z'

Comment: @Meysam: You're quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right. I've never thought about it before, or seen it listed, but it is quite common in "What's he do?"

It's not that surprising if you think about it, because the "d" of "does" gets assimilated into the "t" of "what", so it becomes "whattəz" or "whadəz"