# the slang contraction of "what'd he" as in the sentence "what'd he come at you with"

Tags: slang, formality, colloquialisms, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

What is the slang contraction of "What'd he" as in the sentence "What'd he come at you with"? "What'd he" is already a contraction but I mean in the same manner like whatcha = what're you=what've you, for example. I made a comprehensive search, but I didn't find the answer. Is the slang contraction the same whether it's contraction of "What would he" or "What do he" or "What did he" etc? If there isn't the well-established contraction of "What'd he", how would you shorten it? What does the aforementioned sentence "What'd he come at you with" sound like when it's spoken very quickly as in a slang speech?

Comment: Contractions don't have to be unambiguous. In the UK, 'He has a lovely wife; also, he's a fine son who is always willing to help people' is ambiguous. Slang expressions can be even less well behaved. See [Does “he's” mean both “he is” and “he has”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58921/does-hes-mean-both-he-is-and-he-has).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We use *whatcha* differently to the Americans, don't we? To us it is a greeting - 'Whatcha Fred, how's the missus?'. But Americans use it as short for e.g. 'What are you doing in there?' - 'Whatcha doing in there?'.

Comment: I thought that was 'Wotcha!'

Answer (score 2):

For how it actually sounds, spoken fast ...

What did he = What'd he = (?) W'a'd'ee

Answer (score 2):

I think ***what'd he*** is the shortest form of "what did he..." that would be readily understood. You might get away with ***"what'dee"*** - as in "What'dee say?" Also:

*"whatta ya"* (what do you) 
*"why'n'cha"* (why don't you)
*"didja"*  (did you)
and *"why'd'ya"* (why did you)